# remove id's from background images in visual composer

Tags: wordpress

It seems like visual composer sometimes adds an ID to background images.
For example .jpg?id=25339
Any tips to how I can remove this feature?

Comment: I have never used Visual Composer but those IDs look like a form of cache control. Might consider looking in any cache settings, if any.

Comment: No caching at the moment, I could modify the visual composer files a little which removed the id, but wouldn't be able to update then + it broke a few other things.
so was thinking there must be some small preg function you could add to functions.php which removed ids from jpg's